# { "errors": [ { "detail": "Bad Request. The JSON payload should be inside a root property called 'sheet1'

Tags: python, json, properties, request, root

I posted a question about this code earlier and got an answer that got rid of one problem but now I'm getting a new error, and I dont uderstand the error or bug. Also im coding on PyCharm using a Mac, if that changes anything. The code is from lecture 333, of 100 days of code
by Dr. Angela Yu. Thanks to @Tim Roberts for the help on my last problem!

```
#------------New_code------------#

import requests
from datetime import datetime

GENDER = "male"
WEIGHT_KG = 58.740212
HEIGHT_CM = 177.8
AGE = 13

APP_ID = "be2*****"
API_KEY = "4fa82da*************************"

exercise_endpoint = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise"
sheet_endpoint = "https://api.sheety.co/0a5644021c9c3815973ccd3f25595467/myWorkouts/sheet1"

exercise_text = input("Tell me which exercises you did: ")

headers = {
    "x-app-id": APP_ID,
    "x-app-key": API_KEY,
}

parameters = {
    "query": exercise_text,
    "gender": GENDER,
    "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
    "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
    "age": AGE
}

response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, json=parameters, headers=headers)
result = response.json()

today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%X")

bearer_headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {'TOKEN'}"
}

for exercise in result["exercises"]:
    sheet_inputs = {
        "workout": {
            "date": today_date,
            "time": now_time,
            "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
            "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
            "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
        }
    }

    sheet_response = requests.post(sheet_endpoint, json=sheet_inputs, headers=bearer_headers)

    print(sheet_response.text)

#------------New_output------------#
Tell me which exercises you did: (I entered: run 3 miles)
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Bad Request. The JSON payload should be inside a root property called 'sheet1'. Check https://sheety.co/docs for more details."
    }
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Maybe `sheet_response = requests.post(sheet_endpoint, json={"root": sheet_inputs}, headers=bearer_headers)`?

Comment: Hello CristiFati, thanks for the help, I tried your new code, but I'm still getting the same error, however, I'm going to mess around with that code and see if a variation of it will help. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, just to let you know I tried this variation of the code:                                                                                 
sheet_response = requests.post(sheet_endpoint, json={"sheet1": sheet_inputs}, headers=bearer_headers)                                                                                         
and now am not getting an error but it's not updating my google sheet:                {
  "sheet1": {
    "id": 2
  }
}

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead "workout" you should use "sheet1"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In this part you specify /sheet1

```
sheet_endpoint = "https://api.sheety.co/0a5644021c9c3815973ccd3f25595467/myWorkouts/sheet1"
```

But lower you try to add data in non-exist table "workout"

```
for exercise in result["exercises"]:
    sheet_inputs = {
        "workout": {
            "date": today_date,
            "time": now_time,
            "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
            "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
            "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.
MAke sure that in sheet1 there are already the desired columns present before you run for sheety request.post method.

just for example.
{'sheet1': {'date': '15/04/2023', 'time': '17:38:36', 'exercise': 'Walking', 'duration': 120, 'calories': 588}}
this is my data which i want to add in sheet1 using sheety, then make sure the date time    exercise    duration    calories   columns are present in the sheet1 before you run your request.post().

Also for payload, there is no need to mention the sheet1 as suggested above.
sheet_response = requests.post(
sheet_endpoint,
json = sheet_inputs
)
this was able to add rows in the google sheet successfully (without any authentication. if you have authentication, add parameters accordingly).
Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can rename sheet1 in your google sheets to 'workout'.
or in the code you can do this changes

```
for exercise in result["exercises"]:
sheet_inputs = {
    "workout": {
        "date": today_date,
        "time": now_time,
        "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
        "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
        "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
    }
}
```

rename it to sheet1 like this

```
for exercise in result["exercises"]:
sheet_inputs = {
    "sheet1": {
        "date": today_date,
        "time": now_time,
        "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
        "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
        "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
    }
}
```